# Keep getting "Server Rejected" when I try to upload a file to a Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-app-maker, google-drive-picker

So my app was working (was able to upload file to a Google Drive folder). But today, it doesn't work all of a sudden. Whenever I want to upload the file, it keeps saying "server rejected" which I'm not sure why.

I use drive picker and onPickerInit, this is what I put as a custom action:

```
var folderId = "1t6MrDgiWj0tHEEX0QgxhLerDuDIht1gPPP"; //the desired folder id - I put a fake Id
pickerBuilder.SW.Vq["0"].mc.parent = folderId;
```

Comment: Are you sure the folder exists and that you have permissions to upload files to the folder?

Comment: did you try redeploying to see if it just needs reauthorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just put this on the server script and it fixes the problem:

`function writeAccess() {
       DriveApp.addFile();
    }`

Comment: Wow, I've spent too long looking for this answer...